# openPowerlink in Eclipse project

Tags: c, eclipse, gcc, cmake

I'm working in a project including openPowerlink protocol stack (https://sourceforge.net/projects/openpowerlink/)

The stack comes as a linux kernel module or a userspace library. I have to use the kernel module for performance purposes.

There is an abstraction layer for accessing the kernel module in user applications, but this abstraction layer is not encapsulated in a kind of library.

They are using cmake as a cross plattform build system, building demo application and kernel module worked like a charm, but I don't understand how I can use this stuff in my own application.

I've seen the demo application (who includes abstration layer) uses only some files of stack, but I don't know how I can setup a eclipse project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i've finallay figured out which source and header files you need:

Source Files:

```
EplApiLinuxUser.c
EplDebug.c (optional)
```

Header Files:

```
Debug.h
EplAmi.h
EplApiLinux.h
EplCfg.h
EplCfm.h
EplDef.h
EplErrDef.h
EplEvent.h
EplFrame.h
Epl.h
EplInc.h
EplInstDef.h
EplLed.h
EplNmt.h
EplObd.h
EplPdo.h
EplSdoAc.h
EplSdo.h
EplSection-default.h
EplTarget.h
EplVersion.h
ftraceDebug.h
global.h
```